# How to fix undefined reference to `b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)'

Tags: c++, box2d, clion

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>

int main() {
    int32 velocityIterations = 6;
    int32 positionIterations = 2;
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);
    b2World world(gravity);

    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```

The error I get:

> undefined reference to `b2World::b2World(b2Vec2 const&)'

When I try linking Box2D in CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(C:/Users/blahblah/CPPLibs)
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld Box2D)
```

I get:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lBox2D

How I can properly import Box2D to my project?

Comment: create b2World constructor

Comment: @MichelJord I did `b2World world(gravity);`, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compile because your linker can't find Box2D source files. You have to add .cpp files manually (which is a poor solution) or create a static library with Box2D source code (e.g. .../Box2D_v2.3.0/Box2D/Box2D). Generated file (e.g. libBox2D.a) add to your project and it should be compiled without any problems.

Comment: How I can generate the .a file?

Comment: If you could please add how to make it step by step, I'm new in C++. I tried this: http://jantzeno.github.io/2013/08/06/Box2D-command-line.html but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You can use Code::Blocks to generate .a file. Create new project and choose 'static library'. Then you can remove main.c file because it's useless. Next right click on your project icon and choose 'Add files recursively'. Select path <your path>/Box2D_v2.3.0/Box2D/Box2D. Then select Project -> Build options -> Search directories -> Compiler -> Add and select <your path>/Box2D_v2.3.0/Box2D. Compile it and enjoy ;)

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE (CLion is better IMO), it can collide with CLion. Do I have to install it only for making .a file? If you have Code::Blocks could you make it for me? If not, I'll make it anyway ;)

Comment: Found portable Code::Blocks. I'll try to compile it. If it failed, I'll tell you.

Comment: I was trying to find the easiest way to generate .a file, and in my opinion this is very simple way to do it. I compiled with GNU GCC Compiler MinGW 4.9.2 and it works perfectly. I choose C::B because it's really simple IDE and i didn't know which IDE you use :)

Comment: Ok, I generated libBox2D.a, now, how to import it?

Comment: C::B -> Project -> Build options... -> Linker settings. Choose debug and click add. Find your .a file. That's all :) I've never worked in CLion so I can't help with it. Probably this is very similar way to do this in CLion. Good luck :)

Comment: Anyway, I'll try to figure it out. Thanks!